# Пишет ошибку-list indices must be integers or slices, как исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests

```
url1="https://blockchain.info/multiaddr?active=1PVyuZZfUa2QeU2S14QvdVRv3CqPxbhur3|1BALRjHSDtepK186o8yR4YZi6T88F6G5L"
    rr = requests.get(url1)
    jsonresponse = json.loads(rr.text)
    df = jsonresponse['addresses']['address'] + ':balance:' + jsonresponse['addresses']['final_balance']
    if jsonresponse['addresses']['final_balance'] >= 0:
        print(df)
        write = open('\\BTCballiorqq.txt', "a")
        write.write(df)
    elif jsonresponse['addresses']['final_balance'] == 0:
        print(df)
```

Как исправить если есть другие варианты?Просто решил поработать с блиотекой.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следующий код будет работать, расскажу об исправлениях.

Исправление 1 - `jsonresponse['addresses']` возвращает список словарей, соответственно, чтобы обратиться к следующему словарю, нужно сначала обратиться к элементу списка, что и делает строчка `jsonresponse['addresses'][0]`, после этого можно уже дальше обращаться к словарям `jsonresponse['addresses'][0]['address']`. Так же `jsonresponse['addresses'][0]['final_balance']` возвращает числовое значение, вы пытаетесь его сложить со строкой, что вызовет `TypeError`, поэтому это значение приводим к строковому виду `str(jsonresponse['addresses'][0]['final_balance'])`

Исправление 2 - аналогично обращаемся к элементу списка, а после к словарю. Так же у вас неправильная логика программы, здесь следует поставить знак `>` вместо `>=`, т.к, при балансе равном нулю в вашем коде второе условие никогда не выполнится.

Исправление 3 - Вы открываете текстовый файл с помощью `open` без контекстного менеджера `with`, а потом забываете его закрыть, это плохая практика. Лучше использовать контекстный менеджер `with as`, дабы файл по выполнению всех действий над ним закрывался

```py
import requests
import json
url1="https://blockchain.info/multiaddr?active=1PVyuZZfUa2QeU2S14QvdVRv3CqPxbhur3|1BALRjHSDtepK186o8yR4YZi6T88F6G5L"
rr = requests.get(url1)
jsonresponse = json.loads(rr.text)
df = jsonresponse['addresses'][0]['address'] + ':balance:' + str(jsonresponse['addresses'][0]['final_balance']) # исправление 1
if jsonresponse['addresses'][0]['final_balance'] > 0: # исправление 2
    print(df)
    with open('btc.txt', 'a') as f: # исправление 3
       f.write(df + '\n') 
elif jsonresponse['addresses']['final_balance'] == 0:
    print(df)
```

Comment: Благодарю понял.Пробывал поразному код писать я.Опять забыл про список .

Comment: @wetru если ответ вам помог, то можете пометить его как правильный