# Ошибка в питон "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, json, requests

```
import requests
print('Studio Ghibli -' + 'это японская студия анимационных фильмов, соучредителями которой являются: \n Исао Такахата, Хаяо Миядзаки, Тошио Сузуки и Ясуёси Токума.\n'
                     ' Компания начала свою деятельность в июне 1985 года в качестве дочернего предприятия Tokuma Shoten Co., Ltd.\n'
                     'Все названия аниме от Studio Ghibli - https://yaokino.ru/multfilmy-studii-ghibli-spisok')
BASE_URL = "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films/"
main_data = requests.get(BASE_URL).json()
name = input("\nНапишите название аниме и мы дадим информацию о ней: ")
print(f"Дата выхода аниме - {main_data['release_date']}")
```

Первый раз делаю библеотику в питоне. Запуская этот код, вы пишите какое-то аниме от Studio Ghibli, и оно выдает дату выхода аниме, но на данный момент он выдает только ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\122\Desktop\2\5\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(f"Название аниме - {main_data['title']}")
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

`print(main_data)` выдает:
 `[{'id': '2baf70d1-42bb-4437-b551-e5fed5a87abe', 'title': 'Castle in the Sky', 'original_title': '天空の城ラピュタ', 'original_title_romanised': 'Tenkū no shiro Rapyuta', 'image': 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2/npOnzAbLh6VOIu3naU5QaEcTepo.jpg']`

Comment: во-первых, в вашем коде нет никакого использования api, особенно Studio Ghibli. во-вторых, это не ошибка в библиотеке, а ошибка в вашем коде. выведите на печать ваш main_data и посмотрите, что в нем.

Comment: @strawdog, вывел, а где именно ошибка у меня? Как это делать?

Comment: ну так покажите, что вы вывели, хотя бы часть.  судя по ошибке, у вас там список, а не словарь.

Comment: @strawdog, да там список. Изменил пост

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Пишет ошибку-list indices must be integers or slices, как исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366259/%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы получаете список словарей. вам нужно найти в нем такой словарь, в котором поле title совпадает с введенной пользователем строкой. и уже из этого словаря доставать данные по ключам. Вот так, например:

```
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films/"
main_data = requests.get(BASE_URL).json()
title = "Spirited Away"
release_date = [x["release_date"] for x in main_data if x["title"]==title][0]
print(release_date)
```

> 2001